Making antenna elements with copper wire lashed to a steel rod
For making stealthy antennas with rigid elements, I want the elements to be thin but stiff. Steel is stiff and is a conductor, but not a great one. I was wondering about using thin steel rod (say 1/8 inch or 3mm) with thin copper wire lashed or glued to it.
Let's assume

The element is for a 100W antenna.
The wire is not necessarily insulated but could be (I suppose non-insulated is an advantage to reduce the dimension).
HF frequencies (plus maybe 50 MHz).
Antenna is temporary so doesn't need to be super-rugged.

It would be sort of like copper coated steel wire, but the copper is lumped.
What would be the effect of this, in terms of efficiency? Would much of the RF energy couple into the steel, and then experience I^2*R loss? Or might the RF largely "ignore" the steel?
Alternatively I could just use steel and not worry about the power loss, but if I can easily improve upon that I might try it.
I'm aware there are endless antennas and ways to build them, but am specifically interested in this technique.

You may also find success with copper clad aluminum wire or tubing

Without simulating it... my gut feeling would be that the steel and copper will share the currents approximately by the ratio of their projected surface area. With some modification for the way the fields won't reach into cracks. Because the two wires are in contact, or have good capacitive coupling, they will be at essentially the same electrical potential all the way up.
So a thin copper wire on a thicker steel rod will make no difference (even though the thin wire alone may have been a better antenna.
Two equal diameter wires may reduce the losses to half those of steel.
Once the steel is mostly obscured by the copper, the losses will be similar to plain copper.
The best strength/price/performance ratio would be several fine wires around the steel rod, so the copper "coating" is thin.
Note that the copper wires must run along the length, not be wound tightly around the steel like a spring.

You will find many questions and answers on this site, discussing the losses from switching from copper to steel. It depends strongly on the type of steel, diameter and the frequency. For example on a steel 108" whip the loss is neglegible. But on a 40 m long stealth end-fed halfwave with 0.3 mm stainless wire, it's more than 10 dB.

Thanks. Your intuition was one of mine.  However, I had another intuition that nature would seek the lower loss solution - I don't know where I got that intuition but it sort of sounds cool :)

You will have capacitance issues if you are planning to attach the copper to the rod with insulators. If you plan to make the steel rod part of the antenna, you have differing velocities, which to me will make the frequency calculations harder. Beyond that, when you use very thin elements you reduce the bandwidth and power that can be handled by the antenna. There is an additional concern with using dissimilar metals; if you plan to have the antenna up for a long time and the steel and copper are both antenna elements, the connecting surfaces will tend to corrode more quickly over time leading to all kinds of weirdness. I know you say the antenna is temporary.. but in my experience solutions are only temporary if they don't work. :)
My recommendation is to model it in EZNEC and experiment! While the modeling will help you to get close, the experimentation is where the fun is and where reality meets theory.
If I could suggest, make everything a bit longer than your calculations say it needs to be. It's reasonable to expect that whatever you make will not match the ideal antenna that you model, and it's always easier to make things shorter than it is to make them longer. :)

I once made an antenna for 50 Mhz using 6 mm copperweld. Very stiff, thin copper on steel. https://www.copperweld.com/products/signal-wire/products/coaxial-core I got it from someone working with Ericsson about 60 years ago. Copperweld has a lot of products, the one I used was for 'harden the power grid' https://www.copperweld.com/products/power-grid/products/century Maybe you should contact them. It is necessary to protect the copper with some suitable paint, or better, a thin layer of electrolytic gold.


It would be sort of like copper coated steel wire, but the copper is lumped.

Without having simulated this, either: fully agree with tomnexus. RF currents will be pushed mostly to the outermost parts of a conductor. So, a piece of copper next to the steel core isn't going to do much.
The usual solution to that in cables with steel core for high tensile strength is to actually have a complete sheath of copper wires around the core, or for single, thin conductors, to plate the steel with copper. There's multiple ways of doing that, but for "at home" works that "only" leave you with toxic / groundwater-dangerous heavy metal salts but no poisonous organic compounds, copper(II)-sulfate electroplating is the go-to method to coat less electronegative metals like iron with a layer of copper. Polish afterwards, and coat the copper layer with lacquer: copper oxidizes very quickly, and unlike say copper pans where the thin copper oxide layer doesn't interfere with the function of the pan, the outmost layer is where most current "wants" to flow.
Here's the problem: The ferromagnetic nature of steel is bad for antennas in your frequency range. Iron has high magnetic permeability, meaning that the H-field in the core is high. This pushes the current even further out into a thinner layer of the core, as far as I can tell. Which is probably fine if your copper layer is uniform, but made-at-home copper cladding probably isn't.
So, maybe stay away from iron, steel, nickel, cobalt, or see whether you can buy industrially copper-coated steel rods.
Aluminium is probably a good compromise. At 3mm diameter, it's already relatively stiff, and it's not as bad a conductor as iron. It also is very light compared to its stiffness (that's why there's aluminium bike frames), which makes support structures that you would need for a 3mm diameter steel rod of say 2m length as well smaller and more stealthy.
However, honestly: the more you can make your antenna narrowband, the better the relationship between mechanical size and effective area (or gain) can be. So, maybe going "stealthy" primarily means "smaller" and that means primarily not trying to make a single antenna that covers all of HF (that's a full decade!) and then some, but to build a small loop antenna that you put more effort into matching for the subbands you care about (and carry a matching network per sub-band). You can still make these rigid, e.g. by embedding the loop in a pipe or a board. (I personally think a basketball backboard with the feed running down the mast  is always going to be higher in neighborhood acceptance than even the slimmest wire antenna. And you can put loops in the hoop and along the backboard edge for orthogonal polarizations!)

Thanks for your ideas. I have built a number of antennas using different materials, and was just thinking about another technique. Besides wire, I use a lot of Al rod and sometimes semi-rigid copper wire for short elements. Probably most of the builds weren't used more than once :)  My question was inspired by the copper coated steel wire that you mention, which of course has a much different geometry.
The problem with discussions about stealth is that it is so situational.  I mentioned stealth in my question to provide my motivation, i.e., thin rigid antenna elements.

@gschro thanks for the kind words! yeah, I think this is a very good question, and no matter what antennas you end up building, investigating materials can only make you smarter and enriches this site's corpus of knowledge :)

I use stainless steel 1/4-wavelength vertical monopole antennas all the time. The base is rather thick, but the tip is thin (telescoping rod antenna, MFJ1979, and Chinese knockoff that is actually superior to MFJ). Just use one of those and save the effort.
You can look at my QRZ page, where I have QSO maps. Most of them are 20, 17, 15, 12, and 10m CW. Some 5W, 10W, 100W mixed. I've done park-to-park and summit-to-summit with Japan, New Zealand, Australia, the UK, Germany, Switzerland, the Canary Islands, Balearic Island, Madeira Island, etc., etc., cuts through pileups ok, except major DXpeditions.
When I'm a bit more serious, I use Spiderbeam HD 12m mast or something else with an 18AWG stranded wire, but when I'm doing a bicycle portable operation or doing parks on the air from my SUV, a 5.5m-long Chinese stainless whip works well. The performance difference is smaller than that from the ground soil, ionospheric condition, and how well the radials are deployed, so I don't worry much about it.
